# Tailwind CSS in next.JS server isn't rendering any styles

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, next.js, tailwind-css

I have a basic web server using node.js, next.js, Webpack, and Tailwind CSS.

However, when I run the server, none of the Tailwind styles are applied, and so the page renders without any styling.

**Expected**
[image]

**Actual**
[image]

**/styles/tailwind.css**

```
@tailwind  base;
@tailwind  components;
@tailwind  utilities;
```

**/package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build:css": "postcss styles/tailwind.css -o styles/main.css",
    "dev": "node server.js",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start -p $PORT",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run build",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.2",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "dotenv": "^7.0.0",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^1.7.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^0.19.1",
    "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.12",
    "isomorphic-unfetch": "^3.0.0",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "next": "^9.0.1",
    "next-cookies": "^1.1.2",
    "next-redux-wrapper": "^3.0.0-alpha.2",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "ramda": "^0.26.1",
    "react": "^16.8.4",
    "react-cookie": "^3.1.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.4",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.1",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "react-timeago": "^4.4.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-immutable": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-immutable-state-invariant": "^2.1.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.0.2",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.86.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.3.0",
    "styled-components": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": "^9.8.6",
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.0",
    "css-loader": "^4.3.0",
    "postcss-cli": "^8.0.0",
    "postcss-import": "^12.0.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^4.0.3",
    "postcss-preset-env": "^6.7.0",
    "precss": "^4.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^1.8.12",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3",
    "webpack": "^4.44.2",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.12.0"
  }
}
```

**/postcss.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    require('precss'),
    require('postcss-import'),
    require('tailwindcss'),
    require('autoprefixer'),
    require('postcss-preset-env'),
  ]
}
```

**/tailwind.config.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  future: {},
  purge: [],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [],
}
```

**/pages/_app.js**

```js
import '../styles/tailwind.css'
//....
```

**/pages/sample.js**

```js
import React from "react";

import '../styles/tailwind.css'

export default function Sample() {
  return (
    <div className="p-4 bg-white rounded shadow">
      <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold">Next.js</h1>
      <p className="text-gray-500">
        with Tailwind CSS & postcss-preset-env. Now uses tailwind purge method for
        production builds.
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**/next.config.js**

```js
const { parsed: localEnv } = require('dotenv').config();
const webpack = require('webpack');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

const path = require('path');
const Dotenv = require('dotenv-webpack');

// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  target: 'serverless',
  serverRuntimeConfig: {
    // Will only be available on the server side
  },
  env: {
    //...
  },
  webpack(config) {
    config.plugins = config.plugins || [];

    const rule = {
      test: /\.css$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader']
    }

    config.module.rules.push(rule)

    config.plugins = [
      ...config.plugins,

      // Read the .env file
      new Dotenv({
        path: path.join(__dirname, '.env'),
        systemvars: true,
      }),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin()
    ];

    return config;
  },
};
```

Comment: Your generated styles should be in main.css, so try importing main.css instead of tailwind.css on your pages

Comment: @NilsSchlüter That fixed!!!! Thank you so much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The generated styles are usually preferred  to be in `main.css`,

Try changing

```
import '../styles/tailwind.css'
```

to

```
import'./main.css
```

Hope it helps !